# Servlet requests and window.location.href

Tags: java, servlets, http-request

I have a java servlet that sets a request attribute which is served for a particular page. On that page, there is some javascript to re-direct to a new page with window.location.href= ...

Will the request attribute be available in the redirected page? I realize this question is a bit confusing, I apologize for that, I'm not really sure how to explain it better, but I thank you in advance for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new request will be created for the redirect and you will lose your request-scoped attributes. If you want to retain data, consider storing it in the session instead.

Answer (score 1):

Request attributes live only for the period/scope of the request in which they are set.You should use session scoped attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you redirect to a new page, it's a completely new request and a new request object is created. So anything you had in your earlier request object will be discarded. Try saving your data in session or application scope. This should resolve it.